# inverse limit of $k[x]/(x^n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I know the inverse limit of $k[x]/(x^n)$ is $k[[x]]$ but i can't show the homomorphism between these is onto.

For example
$\alpha:k[[X]]\to\varprojlim k[x]/(x^n)$ by F(x)=family of$ F(x)+(x^n)$. for example $(1+(x),0,5+7x^2+(x^3),3+11x+132x^2+(x^4),0,...)$
is image of things in k[[x]]?

Comment: Do you mean $x^n$?

Comment: Perhaps Tex editing is preferred on this site :)

Comment: Note that the element in your question is NOT in $\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow} k[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$. $\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow} k[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$ contains $(f_i+\langle X^i\rangle)_{i\geq 1}$ such that $f_j+\langle X^i\rangle= f_i+\langle X^i\rangle$ for all $i\leq j$.

Comment: thanks. is it true this homomorphism between $k[[x]]$ to direct limi$k[x]/(x^n)$ is $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i.x^i$go to the family of $(a_0+(x),a_0+a_1.x+(x^2),a_0+a_1.x+a_2.x^2+(x^3),...)$?

Comment: @parisa: Yes, that homomorphism is correct.

Comment: $(1+(x),0,5+7x2+(x^3),3+11x+132x2+(x^4),0,...)$ is not in inverse limit of $k[x]/(x^n)$ since is not in inverse system?is it true?

Comment: @jim:do you know what the above family is not in inverse limit $k[x]/(x^n)$?

Comment: @parisa: I don't understand the grammar of your question, could you rephrase it?

Comment: @jim:sorry my language is not english. I think the $(7+(x),0,2+5x+12x^2+(x^3),1234+3456x+234876x^2=7x^3+(x^4),...)$in inverse limit, then my function is not onto.I cant show this homomorphism is onto.can you to show this onto?

Comment: @parisa: My answer below explains why that element is *not* in the inverse limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element
$$(1+(x),0,5+7x^2+(x^3),3+11x+132x^2+(x^4),0,...)$$
that you're looking at is not in $\varprojlim k[x]/(x^n)$ because it's components do not respect the transition maps.  For example $5 + 7x^2 + (x^3)$ goes to $5 + (x^2)$ under the map $k[x]/(x^3) \to k[x]/(x^2)$, it doesn't go to $0$ as you have in your family.

Once you write down an element that does respect all the transition maps you'll see that if you look at the coefficient of some $x^m$ in the polynomial $f \in k[x]/(x^n)$ and $m < n$ then that coefficient can't change in any of the further elements of your tuple, so it uniquely identifies the coefficient of $x^m$ of a polynomial in $k[[x]]$.